# Print a vertical histogram of data represented by numbers

Tags: java, histogram

I am writing a program that reads 3 non-zero, non-negative integers from a user.  The program is supposed to print three vertical bar lines consisting of asterisks' (*) with the heights equal to the users integers.

I'm having issues with printing the 3rd vertical line straight.  If, for example, the user integers are 3,1 and 8, my console prints the last (3rd) line shifting left upwards, instead of printing a vertical straight line consisting of 8 asterisks.
I tried changing around my print statements, but couldn't figure it out.  Does it have to do with something in my counter?  What am I missing?  Any help would be highly appreciated.  As well, any tips on cleaner and better coding would be nice.
Thank you in advance!

Here is my code so far:

```
    /*call Scanner - prompt userInput*/
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter three non-zero and non-negative integers: ");
    int int1 = userInput.nextInt();
    int int2 = userInput.nextInt();
    int int3 = userInput.nextInt();
            
    /*check for zero and/or negative integers with while-loop) - close Scanner*/
    while (int1 <= 0 || int2 <= 0 || int3 <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println("One or more of your integers is zero or negative. "
                         + "Please enter three non-zero and non-negative integers: ");
        int1 = userInput.nextInt();
        int2 = userInput.nextInt();
        int3 = userInput.nextInt();
    }
    userInput.close();
    
    /*Math.max method - for-loop with counter - print Histogram*/
    System.out.println("Your histogram:");
    int max = Math.max(Math.max(int1, int2), int3);
    for (int i = max; i > 0; i--)
    {
        System.out.print  (i > int1 ? " " : "* ");
        System.out.print  (i > int2 ? " " : "* ");
        System.out.println(i > int3 ? " " : "* ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake.  In your last `for` loop, you have to print two blanks if the asterisk is not printed.

Also, your `Scanner` has to consume the line feed / control return at the end of an input line.

Here's the test run

```
Please enter three non-zero and non-negative integers: 
3 1 8
Your histogram:
    * 
    * 
    * 
    * 
    * 
*   * 
*   * 
* * *
```

Your code is organized nicely.  I'm not sure if you've learned about methods yet, but you can break up your code into methods.

It would be pretty easy to generalize your code to handle a variable number of int inputs.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VerticalHistogream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           /*call Scanner - prompt userInput*/
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter three non-zero and non-negative integers: ");
        int int1 = userInput.nextInt();
        int int2 = userInput.nextInt();
        int int3 = userInput.nextInt();
        userInput.nextLine();
                
        /*check for zero and/or negative integers with while-loop) - close Scanner*/
        while (int1 <= 0 || int2 <= 0 || int3 <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("One or more of your integers is zero or negative. "
                             + "Please enter three non-zero and non-negative integers: ");
            int1 = userInput.nextInt();
            int2 = userInput.nextInt();
            int3 = userInput.nextInt();
            userInput.nextLine();
        }
        userInput.close();
        
        /*Math.max method - for-loop with counter - print Histogram*/
        System.out.println("Your histogram:");
        int max = Math.max(Math.max(int1, int2), int3);
        for (int i = max; i > 0; i--)
        {
            System.out.print  (i > int1 ? "  " : "* ");
            System.out.print  (i > int2 ? "  " : "* ");
            System.out.println(i > int3 ? "  " : "* ");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Such a simple fix.  Thank you kindly :)